# CSS - Float: left on the same line

Tags: css

[image]

```
.htabs { /* horizontal tabs */
    display: table;
}

.htabs li { /* horizontal tab */
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    background: url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAYAAAAGCAYAAADgzO9IAAAAMklEQVQIW2M8e3r/fw4OdgZk8OPHTwbGq5eP/QcxYJIwNlgCpBokAAIwBfglsBqFy3IAqdosZ0m+BQ8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=);
    border-left: 1px solid #e1dfd2;
    border-top: 1px solid #e1dfd2;
    border-right: 1px solid #e1dfd2;
    margin-right: 1px;
    display: table-row;
}

.htabs li a { /* horizontal tab link */
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #444444 !important;
    text-shadow: -1px -1px rgba(229,227,215,1), 1px 1px rgba(229,227,215,1);
    z-index: 1;
    padding: 0 7px;
    line-height: 30px; 
}
```

I'm trying to make a fully responsive website and now i need some help. Look at the picture, when i resize the browser window to a smaller size - "tabs" are moving to the second line what looks bad. How can i force them to stay on one line ?

Comment: You would do better on CSS questions to create a jsFiddle so people can tinker with it in real time.

Comment: I will try to do jsFiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that the thing that you are doing is not the responsive website!

The first step to creating the responsive layouts is to plan out what resolutions you want to cater for. Common resolutions include the `320px` portrait width of smartphones, `768px` portrait width of tablets, `1024px` landscape width of tablets.

In order to create a responsive website, you should use `Media queries`. For example,

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {      
    #content {
        margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    }
}
```

In you case, you must decide what are the size of screen that you want to display in different designs.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) { 


@media screen and (max-width: 758px) { 


}

@media screen and (max-width: 524px) { 

}
```

You can learn how to [Create a responsive website step by step](http://line25.com/tutorials/create-a-responsive-web-design-with-media-queries)

**EDIT** : I just added the `width: 20%;` into the `.htabs li` It makes each `li` tag can be shirked. Moreover, you should change font-size to be smaller and larger depending on the browser size. So, just put the following instruction in each media query and try to modify the font-size to suit the browser size.

```
.htabs li { /* horizontal tab */
    width: 20%;
    ....
}

.htabs li a {
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm already using media queries. Everything else works fine. Wait for fiddle

Comment: @MackoTarana Great so give me the fiddle. I will try to help you solve it or just give me your website's url.

Comment: Second word "us" is moving to the next line. I'll think some more about this. Thanks for your time ;)

Comment: white-space:nowrap; - got it ;) BIG THANKS !

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap the menubar into an element with height and width specified to avoid this. Also, you should add `overflow:hidden` attribute to this wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

you are using "px" instead of "%" and "em , rem" attribute, you should using % or "em" for padding or width in the responsive design,

Comment: But still if i try to add some more tabs it will looks exactly the same.